# Is there a better way of displaying 'Count' of records beside other columns in a select query?

Tags: oracle, query-performance, stored-procedures, oracle-11g-r2, plsql

I have a table with below structure :

```
Test1(c_num  number ,c_first_name varchar2(50), c_last_name varchar2(50))
```

1)There is a `normal index` on `c_num` column.

2)The table has nearly `5 million` records.

I have a procedure as you can see below. I want to display the `Count(*)` along with other columns.I want to know if there are better ways of doing this so that we can have better performance.

```
create or replace procedure get_members(o_result out sys_refcursor) 
  is
begin

open o_result for
  select c_num,
         c_first_name,
         c_last_name,
         (select count(*) from test1) members_cnt -->Is there a better way instead of doing this?
  from test1;

end;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you used there should not cause a problem, because it is a scalar subquery, meaning its result would be automatically cached, and as it has only 1 distinct value, even if `test1` has 5 million rows, the inner query would not be executed 5 million times.

But you can use the analytic version of `count`:

```
select c_num,
       c_first_name,
       c_last_name,
       count(*) over () as members_cnt
from test1;
```

Comment: Thanks. So your point is that "count() over()" is better than "(select count(*) from...)" in terms of performance ?

Comment: @Pani No, and these are not generally exchangable. But in this case, using the subquery requires 1 more table access than the analytic function. The performance difference is rather negligible.

Comment: In the case _as you have presented it_, what's the point?  You will get 5 million row, and each will show exactly the same value MEMBERS_COUNT.  The count will have no relationship at all to the member shown on the individual row.  I strongly suspect your actual case is more complex, in which case you should present it if you want the best possible advice.

Comment: @EdStevens This is a procedure which is being used by the Application in order to show the result. The application shows all the column of the table and also the count of the result.So I need to give the Application , The count of records in this procedure so it can use this .

Comment: @EdStevens I added this part (Count(*)) for the purpose of providing count of all records for the application to use.

Comment: @Pani: Sorry,  but this looks to me like another Technical Solution in search of a Problem.  It is highly /unlikely/ that the application will want all 5 million records - how long would that even take to display?  Also, the Application should be perfectly capable of counting what it retrieves for itself.

Comment: @PhillW. Thanks . I will tell this to our Application team . I did not say anything cause I do not have any knowledge regarding front end programming . May be they have a good reason for this ! But I'll tell them this . thank you all.

Comment: "May be they have a good reason for this" - Dangerous assumption, I would suggest.  What they've requested is a "quick and dirty" way of getting a count of the rows, rather than them doing a bit more work, either calling a second, "count", method or simply counting the rows that they get back.  IME, Developers have /very/ short-term focus, obsessing about fixing the problem immediately to hand.  (Mind you, that /is/ what they're paid for!)